# Is it possible to "detach" from an interactive PBS job?

Tags: job-scheduling, hpc, pbs, qsub

as the title says I am looking for a possibility to keep a job which was started by e.g. `qsub -I some_script.qsub` open (because the job is stopped when ssh connection is closed).

I already tried to achieve this by `qalter <jobID> -W interactive=False`. This was my best guess so far and I can not find more suitable information at the moment.

For reference:

- Scheduler PBS Torque

> -bash-4.2$ qstat --version Version: 4.2.10 Commit: ddf5c4f40091b6157164a8846e5b60f42a5ae7f6

Thank you!

EDIT: Like stated in the comments detaching and reattaching the ssh session is an improvement for now but not exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Would using something like GNU Screen or tmux to detach your session where the shell calling qsub be sufficient?  Or are you talking about the ssh session dropping between the login node and the compute node?

Comment: Let me add a little bit for clarification. I am working on some research project with very experimental code. I do not use any kind of GUI. There is  a lot of debugging involved at the moment so I use interactive jobs a lot. From time to time there are parts of the program which take a lot of time. (up to a few hours - and yes it is necessary to test it like this). During this time I would like to be able to close the terminal with ssh connection or maybe shut down the computer without terminating the job(what is happening with an interactive job by definition - I guess)

Comment: I second Paul - start `screen` or `tmux` on the head node, then issue `qsub` in the new session. You can then detach and reattach to the session later on. That only works if you can reliably log into the same head node. Some clusters distribute incoming SSH connections over several head nodes and there is no guarantee that you'll end up on the same node for successive SSH connections.

Comment: That is not exactly what I was looking for but an improvement for now. I was hoping to alter the job attributes and connect from the job not only the ssh session. I will do a little bit of further research as well. Thanks so far